# "Match" two Layers with points (GPX)

Tags: qgis

I have two GPX-Vector-Layers with points. One "Todo-File" (Locations that I want to visit) and one "Done-File" (locations that I had visited extract from the GPS-Data from phote I had taken).

I have these two layers in QGIS and what I want is a seperate layer, that includes all points, that dont have a (fuzzy) match (=all Points that I really dont visited).

Is there a chance to get this? In best case with a tolerance (Done-Point is/is not within a radius of 100m from a Todo-Point)

Comment: Buffer all visited points by 100 m, then `select by location` all points in the "unvisited" layer which are within the buffer, then reverse selection - voila.

Comment: Thank you. Thats it (but I cant choose "metres"; I had to choose "degrees" and uses "0,001"

Comment: Then save the GPX to shape and change the CRS during export to a m-based.

Comment: What is "m-based"? I cant find something sounds like this (in german version)

Comment: Mercador - I see now ;)

Comment: m = meters, so you need to find a fitting UTM-zone. Most likely 32N (western Germany) or 33N (eastern Germany)